# App upgraded to 3.2 getting routing error for stylesheet application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am in a weird situation. I have an app that was created in 3.1. It recently was upgraded to Rails 3.2.6 and, for the first time, I have started working with layouts and views. (Don't ask. I've been using the app in console mode and as a database manager)

Now I have a controller and some models and when I access the default page, everything is fine but I see in the logs, the following error:

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 13:54:45 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
```

There is an application.css file in 'app/assets/stylesheets'. It is currently blank.

I've seen lots of other people asking this question but none of the solutions/answers seem to apply to me though I can't say why. Here is what my layout/application.html.erb file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <% if current_user %>
        <title>MY TITLE - <%= current_user.full_name %></title>
    <% else %>
        <title>MY TITLE</title>
    <% end %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav_div">
    <% if current_user %>
      Logged in as <%= current_user.name %> (<%= current_user.email %>).
      <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %> or
      <%= link_to "Log In", login_path %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="flash_div">
    <% if flash[:alert] %>
      <p class="flash-error"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if flash[:notice] %>
      <p class="flash-notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
    <% end %>   
</div>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you copy/paste application.css in public/stylesheets? Might be a problem with the asset pipeline

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto, interesting. That made the error go away. Is this a fix, though?

Comment: More a work-around, unless you don't want to use the asset pipeline. If you do want to use it, tell me what's your environment, and for this environment, give me the configuration you're using for the pipeline (options like config.assets.<something>)

Comment: I think I do want to use the asset pipeline. I want to do things the right way; i can't have problems down the road. Problem is, I don't think i know enough to answer the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the pipeline turned on in application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```